# Can a multi core processor make parallel network connections?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, network-programming, python-asyncio

I am currently having a use case wherein need to hit a a REST endpoint with some data(~20 MB) present in a file and upload it(HTTP POST). The machine that I am using for this action is of the type *Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz (40 cores, 375 GB RAM)* . The problem now is that I would need to make around 8000 such network calls ( with the cumulative payload size being around 200 GB) within a span of 1 hour .
This machine is connected to a 10GBps bandwidth line.

Sequential execution is bad idea for me, and am looking at parallelizing the calls.
Currently evaluating the asyncio library which is better for I/O bound ops (compared to multiprocessing, as there is no processing at all to be done).

I was thinking the most optimal solution for this. Will there be advantage of using a multi-core approach here, since all the data needs to flow out through the same single interface (NIC process)?

Found this 12 year old question: [Take advantage of multi core processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327881/is-there-a-way-to-take-advantage-of-multi-core-when-dealing-with-network-connect) ,but it mostly speaks from a consumption perspective( how do you spin multi core applications to work on the incoming data in parallel). I have no qualms in switching to a more concurrency-friendly programming language like Java, if it serves my use case.

Comment: If you have a single network connection your messages are sequential as they leave your network device. Paralleling connections is less of a consideration than having a very low overhead for each connection which is a different emphasis to what you describe.

Comment: "Sequential execution is bad idea for me": why? "... am looking at parallelizing the calls." You can parallelize the calls, but you can't parallelize the single network you are feeding. But you do have more than enough bandwidth for this task: by my back of the envelope you only need 0.4GBps.

Comment: With all liberty to make it sequential, the consumer of this program's output downstream is a time constrained one. Again ,I have upstream jobs to be completed before I can kickstart my process. So in a nutshell, we are looking to squeeze every ounce of possible efficiency here. As you said, it still has to go through a single wire, but since its a file, that there is some encoding to be done before transfer, which requires some compute power, I wanted to keep the CPU busy doing something. Might sound bit paranoid here, haven't yet tested this yet fully, will update once I have the results.

Answer (score 2):

asyncio will do for you. If you hit a bottleneck,  there is a chance (small) you could get better parallelization creating alias network cards that go through the same connection - but this would just work around bottlenecks in your network stack not related to the Python runtime.

I don't think with these numbers reading your data from disk is an issue - if it were, that means you should take care of using some lib for async file reading as well (using one should not hurt, though.)

Likely Python will need to copy your data from one place to other if you do this with straightforward file "open" - so using memory mapped files for your data could help. as you are saying it is a "rest" endpoint, probably you will have to encode your data so that it is http escaped. Usually REST likes text-data. In this case, you will definitely want to use the process pool executor.

You can tap on some of those cores, as there will be copying around  of data anyway (and likely decoding to text, re-encoding as a field in an HTTP request). You can still use asyncio, and use a `concurrents.future.ProcessPoolExecutor` along with the asyncio `loop.run_in_executor` call (it can be simpler code to write than using the executor in sync code, as checking the call results is straightforward)